# "Q js is undefined." while trying to resolve promise from aurelia-breeze in test method(karma+jasmine)

Tags: typescript, breeze, karma-jasmine, q, aurelia

I am consistently getting an error while trying to resolve a promise from **aurelia-breeze** in a test method for an aurelia(**typescript + breeze**) application.

Testing framework used is `karma+jasmine`.

Version of the `aurelia-breeze` package is `1.0.0`

> Aurelia breeze makes use of **es promise** resolver instead of **Q.js**, but the
>   test method is searching for **Q.js** to resolve the promise returned
>   from breeze.

I have tried to add the `Q` library to the `window` object from the `spec` file. But the `breeze.debug.js` is trying to access the `Q` js from the `window` object before it is set in the `spec` file.

this didn't resolve the issue.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```js
import {configure as configureAureliaBreeze} from 'aurelia-breeze/index';
import {Container} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';

const container = new Container();
configureAureliaBreeze({ container, globalResources: () => {} });

// ... tests ...
```

Breeze depends on Q for promises and jQuery for ajax.  Aurelia-breeze shims both of those dependencies with ES6 promises and the aurelia http-client respectively.  The code above effectively simulates what would happen in a `.plugin('aurelia-breeze')` call when running your aurelia application.

https://github.com/jdanyow/aurelia-breeze/blob/master/src/index.js#L15-L16

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I was able to resolve the issue using the above snippet with a small change.

`import {Container} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';`